# What is the best practice for updating data via mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is two ways to update data using mongoose.

1. Using model methods, for example `User.updateOne({username}, {$set: {age}})`
2. Find document, then change its properties and save it. Like this:

```js
const user = await User.findById(userId)
user.age = age
user.save()
```

Which one is better and why?

Comment: The first method makes one DB call, the second method makes two. I let you do the cost math over thousands or millions of operations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `.save()` method it is actually pulling data from server(MongoDB) to client(Mongoose) and updating the data in memory and then applying the query in server.
Using direct `update` or `updateOne` will perform query directly on server.

So make sure to use queries as much as possible. You can manually check by doing console.time in both the cases
like

```js
console.time('query')
const user = await User.findById(userId)
user.age = age
await user.save()
console.timeEnd('query')
```

and then do this

```js
console.time('query')
await User.updateOne({ _id: userId }, { $set: { age } })
console.timeEnd('query')
```

Comment: I believe you should use `await user.save()` because you are timing it

Comment: yes sorry for that mistake

Comment: Thanks! It was pretty clear

Comment: Consider marking as answered :)